# Can you detect if a user is in Chrome's Guest mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Via a script in a web page, is it possible to find if the user is using Chrome's guest mode?

Comment: Do you mean incognito mode?

Comment: @EliasSoares Guest mode is distinct from incognito mode: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773

Comment: @EliasSoares No, I mean Chrome's guest mode. Been a feature for around 3-4 years.

Comment: Yes, I know. Asked because icognito mode is possible to detect, but guest mode no, since it's just an new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Guest mode** and **Incognito Mode** are different things (see more [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en), thanks @Quethzel Díaz). You can detect Incognito Mode using some hackish methods (see [this](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-chrome-incognito-mode-can-still-be-detected-by-these-methods/) article from late 2019, thanks to @p.s.w.g!). However, those methods are not officially supported by Google and might break in the next patch (for obvious reasons).

*To answer your question:* **It is not possible** to detect Guest Mode currently as it is simply another user in Chrome and appears the same as an unauthenticated user.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's impossible. There may be a variety of ways to detect it (see [this article](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-chrome-incognito-mode-can-still-be-detected-by-these-methods/) from late 2019). However, the developers of Chrome intentionally try to make this very hard. So even if you did find some technique to detect guest or incognito mode, there's no guarantee it won't be broken by a future patch.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Hmm, interesting! Thanks for the link. I'll correct my answer

Comment: Just to clarify, the **Guest mode** and the **Incognito mode** are different things. You can check it out [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6130773?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: @QuethzelDíaz thanks, will include that in my answer as well! :)